# SuiteScript Error - Catch(e) - e undefined

Tags: javascript, suitescript

I have a simple try/catch block in my SuiteScript:

```
try
{
    var csvFile = file.create({name : outputFileName,
                               contents : header,
                               folder : 123,
                               fileType : 'xy'});
}
catch (e)
{
 log.debug({
    title : 'Error',
    details : e.description
  });
}
```

(note that in the above the fileType of 'xy' is intentional, to force the error).

The problem is that when I get to the catch block, 'e' is always undefined. That's how it's logged and that's what the debugger shows. I don't know how that can even happen.

What could be causing this?

Comment: I am seeing the same thing in a 2.1 suitelet I have created and have yet to be able to figure it out.   the "e" is not defined when i get into the catch.   I wondered if any solution was ever determined for this?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that `e` is defined but `e.description` is not? Netsuite uses `e.name` and `e.message` for their custom SuiteScriptError objects (not `e.description`). These can be logged by using dot notation or just with `JSON.stringify(e)`. If it is just a JavaScript Error object (triggered by a syntax error for example), then `JSON.stringify` won't work, but you can still use `e.name` and `e.message`.

Comment: Sadly no, it's ```e``` that's not defined.

Comment: @Bud : if `e` was undefined, accessing `e.description` would trigger an exception. Do you see an exception ? or do you see a message, which is logged, and states `..., details: undefined` ?

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be a solution for you, but there is a free set of SuiteScript abstractions specifically geared for more helpful error catching: https://github.com/datatek-software/netsuite-patterns

Your code would become:

```
const fobj = {
 name : outputFileName,
 contents : header,
 folder : 123,
 fileType : 'xy'
}

const create = safeExecute(file.create, fobj);

if (!create.isSuccess) {
   console.error(create.message);
   console.warning(create.stack);
}
```

If the call is unsuccessful, the isSuccess property will be false and the message property will contain the message exception.  If you need it, the stack property will contain the stack trace for the exception.

More: https://datatek.io/2019/04/25/suitescript-with-a-safety-net/